# Building an Excel formula based on cell references

Tags: excel

Is there any way I can build a formula based on user input including the logical functions?  For example, a user could input

> A1 must be <> 1

A1 would be in a cell (and I can use an indirect), with <> in an adjacent cell and the resulting formula would be **=IF(A1<>1, TRUE, FALSE)**, but the next time the user wants the formula to be

> A1>1

so the cell would have A1 (again using an indirect for the resulting formula) and > in an adjacent cell to result in **IF(A1>1,TRUE,FALSE)**

Comment: Shall always be the same cell (here A1) used in the comparison? Or should be input like 'C23=5' also be processed?

Comment: Only comparisons like <,>,=,<> required or also more complex statements?

Comment: It would always be the same cell.  It will actually be a little more complicated since the metric will be named and I'll use a VLOOKUP to find the actual cell value that metric references, but to keep it simple I'm just using A1 for the example.  I would only need the four oporators you listed

Edit: To clarify, the user might actually be putting a "<>" in a box next to "Revenue" but I'll VLOOKUP "Revenue" to an indirect that points to A1 in that case

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to evaluate each possibility (<>,>=,<=,=) Then use a match or lookup function to choose the correct answer based on the user input.

Comment: That would be the way to go but I have 8 different metrics and 3 criteria per ("<>", "<", ">") so it would be a ton of formulas for all the combinations

Comment: The metrics can be dynamic based on indirect functions. You'd just need to have the criteria (<>, <, >) list built once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***`Convert`*** from ***`Data`*** menu, to split the contain of each cells using blank space as delimiter. You choose L column to write your formula (for example to avoid overlapping due to the split operation), and then you can assembly your criterions by concatenating the contents of the good cells to develop a formula.

you can check by CHER(60), CHAR(61) or CHAR(62) if cells contains respectively the symbol "<", "=" and ">".

hope this can help !

Comment: I think that's getting somewhere, but I still can't get the formula to evaluate without hard keying the operator.  So if i concatenate **=A1&CHAR(60)&A2** (for example), I get 'A1'<'A2' and not 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' as if I did **=A1<A2**

Answer (score 0):

I take the following example, with 2 lines:

1. A1 must be different from one <> 1
2. A1 must be equal or greater than
   zero > 0

In cell B1, I'll have A1. In the next cell C1, I will have "must". In D1 "be", in E1 "different" and so on .. In H1 "<>" and I have "1" in I1.
The second line goes therefore from cell B2 to K2, in J2 I have ">" and K2 to "0".
I type 5 into cell A1 and 0 in cell A2.
In cell M1, I type this line below to have my formula :

```
 =" = IF(" & "A1" & IF(LEN(C1)>2;"";IF(LEFT(C1;1)="<";C1;IF(LEFT(C1;1)="=";C1;IF(LEFT(C1;1)=">";C1;IF(ISNUMBER(C1);C1;"")))))&IF(LEN(D1)>2;"";IF(LEFT(D1;1)="<";D1;IF(LEFT(D1;1)="=";D1;IF(LEFT(D1;1)=">";D1;IF(ISNUMBER(D1);D1;"")))))&IF(LEN(E1)>2;"";IF(LEFT(E1;1)="<";E1;IF(LEFT(E1;1)="=";E1;IF(LEFT(E1;1)=">";E1;IF(ISNUMBER(E1);E1;"")))))&IF(LEN(F1)>2;"";IF(LEFT(F1;1)="<";F1;IF(LEFT(F1;1)="=";F1;IF(LEFT(F1;1)=">";F1;IF(ISNUMBER(F1);F1;"")))))&IF(LEN(G1)>2;"";IF(LEFT(G1;1)="<";G1;IF(LEFT(G1;1)="=";G1;IF(LEFT(G1;1)=">";G1;IF(ISNUMBER(G1);G1;"")))))&IF(LEN(H1)>2;"";IF(LEFT(H1;1)="<";H1;IF(LEFT(H1;1)="=";H1;IF(LEFT(H1;1)=">";H1;IF(ISNUMBER(H1);H1;"")))))&IF(LEN(I1)>2;"";IF(LEFT(I1;1)="<";I1;IF(LEFT(I1;1)="=";I1;IF(LEFT(I1;1)=">";I1;IF(ISNUMBER(I1);I1;""))))) & IF(LEN(J1)>2;"";IF(LEFT(J1;1)="<";J1;IF(LEFT(J1;1)="=";J1;IF(LEFT(J1;1)=">";J1;IF(ISNUMBER(J1);J1;""))))) & IF(LEN(K1)>2;"";IF(LEFT(K1;1)="<";K1;IF(LEFT(K1;1)="=";K1;IF(LEFT(K1;1)=">";K1;IF(ISNUMBER(K1);K1;""))))) & ";" & TRUE & ";" & FALSE & ")"
```

I apply my formula on M2 cells.
After I copy my M1 and M2 cells, I paste By Value in N1.
I replace blank space at the beginning of my formula in N1 et N2 by nothing and then the formula displays results.
Let me know if you have problems with this formula because I developed it in Excel French. I will send you the complete file.